# Mapping remote drives

Tags: vb.net

I am having an issue mapping drives. I have done it many times in the past with no issues for mapping a single drive. This time I am trying to map 2 and having issues. I wanted to see if I can have a fresh set of eyes take a look.

Now what exactly is going on is as follows. The application will Map the drive to O: just fine, but when it tries to map :L nothing happens. No errors, nothing.

I tried running L: by itself, and nothing maps at all. I have tried swapping them, nothing.

*Edit:* Using WinForm

**Functions:**

```
         Public Declare Function WNetAddConnection2 Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetAddConnection2A" _
(ByRef lpNetResource As NETRESOURCE, ByVal lpPassword As String, _
ByVal lpUserName As String, ByVal dwFlags As Integer) As Integer

    Public Declare Function WNetCancelConnection2 Lib "mpr" Alias "WNetCancelConnection2A" _
  (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal fForce As Integer) As Integer

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> Public Structure NETRESOURCE
        Public dwScope As Integer
        Public dwType As Integer
        Public dwDisplayType As Integer
        Public dwUsage As Integer
        Public lpLocalName As String
        Public lpRemoteName As String
        Public lpComment As String
        Public lpProvider As String
    End Structure

    Public Const ForceDisconnect As Integer = 1
    Public Const RESOURCETYPE_DISK As Long = &H1

    Public Function MapDrivePri(ByVal DriveLetter As String, ByVal UNCPath As String) As Boolean

        Dim nr As NETRESOURCE
        Dim strUsername As String
        Dim strPassword As String

        nr = New NETRESOURCE
        nr.lpRemoteName = UNCPath
        nr.lpLocalName = "O:"
        strUsername = "" '(add parameters to pass this if necessary)
        strPassword = "" '(add parameters to pass this if necessary)
        nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK

        Dim result As Integer
        result = WNetAddConnection2(nr, strPassword, strUsername, 0)

        If result = 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function MapDriveBku(ByVal DriveLetter As String, ByVal UNCPath As String) As Boolean

        Dim nr As NETRESOURCE
        Dim strUsername As String
        Dim strPassword As String

        nr = New NETRESOURCE
        nr.lpRemoteName = UNCPath
        nr.lpLocalName = "L:"
        strUsername = "" '(add parameters to pass this if necessary)
        strPassword = "" '(add parameters to pass this if necessary)
        nr.dwType = RESOURCETYPE_DISK

        Dim result As Integer
        result = WNetAddConnection2(nr, strPassword, strUsername, 0)

        If result = 0 Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function
```

**Calling Code:**

```
'Provides the IP
        Dim IP = New StoreIdentifier
        Dim v = IP.Get4digitStoreNumber(StoreNumber.Text)
        Dim s = IP.GetStoreIP(v)

        'Adds last octet to the IP
        Dim Pip = s & "1"
        Dim Bip = s & "2"

        'Adds full path
        Dim Ppath As String = "\\" & Pip & "\C$"
        Dim Bpath As String = "\\" & Bip & "\C$"

        'Maps Drives
        MapDrivePri("O:\", Ppath)
        MapDriveBku("L:\", Bpath)
```

Now the weird part like I said, is O works fine, L will not. and the code is the same.

**Update:**
Doing some more troubleshooting I found something out.

If the IP its trying to map is something like this for example:

> 10.12.30.

It will work fine. However if the IP is like this:

> 10.12.50.

It will map the first one (1) and hang and not map the second one (2)

Now I am super confused...

Comment: Saying you swapped O: and L: is complicated by you hard-coding the driver letters in `MapDriveBku` and `MapDrivePri`. Why not just have one `MapDrive` function and make use of the `DriveLetter` parameter? (Also, you could `Return (result = 0)`.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I did not do that because I assumed you could not, due to the function having a spot to put the drive letter. 'nr.lpLocalName = "O:"'

Comment: You just need to use `nr.lpLocalName = DriveLetter`. But be careful to only pass <letter><colon> to it, or even better, check that it is of the format <letter><colon>.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Was messing around with it and found some other information. I updated the top post so it is easier to read.